# React three fibre switching textures

Tags: three.js, webgl, react-three-fiber

I'm attempting to switch textures while a video is loading to show a preview image, then show the video when it loads.

```
  if (loading)
    return (
      <mesh scale={is360 ? [1, 1, 1] : scale}>
        {is360 ? <sphereBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[500, 60, 40]} /> : <planeBufferGeometry />}
        <meshBasicMaterial
          map={previewTexture}
          side={is360 ? BackSide : FrontSide}
          toneMapped={false}
        ></meshBasicMaterial>
      </mesh>
    );

  return (
    <mesh scale={is360 ? [1, 1, 1] : scale}>
      {is360 ? <sphereBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[500, 60, 40]} /> : <planeBufferGeometry />}
      <meshBasicMaterial side={is360 ? BackSide : FrontSide} toneMapped={false}>
        <videoTexture attach="map" args={[video]} encoding={sRGBEncoding} />
      </meshBasicMaterial>
    </mesh>
```

This gives me

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'requestVideoFrameCallback' in undefined
at new VideoTexture

This goes white when the change happens,

```
 <mesh scale={is360 ? [1, 1, 1] : scale}>
      {is360 ? <sphereBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[500, 60, 40]} /> : <planeBufferGeometry />}
      <meshBasicMaterial needsUpdate={!loading} map={loading ? previewTexture : null} side={is360 ? BackSide : FrontSide} toneMapped={false}>
        {!loading && <videoTexture attach="map" args={[video]} encoding={sRGBEncoding} />}
      </meshBasicMaterial>
    </mesh>
```

Whats the best way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Yoou can check out Reacts **Suspense** it this case it shows image material untoil video is loaded (fallback)
https://codesandbox.io/s/video-texture-39hg8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).